# How to call a random function in Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

in iOS I would simply use this;

```
if (arc4random() % 2 == 0) {
        //Do 1 Thing
    }else{
       // Do another
    }
```

What would be the same method but using Unity3D for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [unity's documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html):

```
if (Random.Range(minVal, maxVal) % 2 == 0) {
        //Do 1 Thing
} else {
       // Do another
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for such a quick reply, regarding the above 'minVal' and 'maxVal' I am not sure about how that works in this instance, as I simply want to just do something every 2nd time, but what would the values be for minVal and maxVal for that situation?

Comment: It's just allow to limit your random, for example, if your minVal is equal to 0 and your maxVal is 5, your result will be always between 0 and 5. So you have to set what will be your smallest and your biggest value from your random.

Comment: Thankyou, although strangely Unity is not liking me using Random.Range it is throwing a resolve error, and suggesting I use UnityEngine.Random.Range  ?

Comment: Thankyou, I am using this `if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2) % 2 == 0) {
   //Do 1 Thing
   showRevive();
  } else{
   // Do nothing
  }`

But it seems to not do it every other time, rather keeps doing it (when it should only be doing it after every 2 turns?

Comment: I didn't get it. What the problem?

Answer (score 1):

random values has been put.

```
 if(Random.Range(-10000, 10000)%2==0)
```